# how to bind aggregate result to account of type list

Tags: apex, aggregateresult

```
Map<Id,Account> mapTargets = new Map<ID,Account>([ Select Id, Name From Account 
    Where Account__c in:TargetAccountIDs]);

 public List<Account> Acc = new List<Account>();
 public List<aggregateResult> Duplicate1 = new List<aggregateResult>();
 Duplicate1 = new List<aggregateResult>([select Enrolled_Flag__c,Electoral_Twin__c,
                 Primary_SPID__c,GivenName__ 
                 Family_Name__c,Date_of_Birth__c, 
                 count(id) 
                     from account;
```

now i am binding the aggregate result to list

```
    for(AggregateResult a: Duplicate1)
    {
         Acc.add(a);
    }
```

now am facing the error like
Incompatible element type AggregateResult for collection of Account

Comment: is your query executing successfully. Aggregate query fields must be grouped by ?

Comment: @sfdcweb I doubt it even compiles, looks like `])` is missing at the last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be as following:

```
  for(AggregateResult a: Duplicate1)
    {   
         Account newAcc = new Account(id=(ID)a.get('id'), GivenName__c= (String)a.get('GivenName__c')..etc);

         Acc.add(newAcc);

    }
```

You need to add to the newAcc  all the fields you'd want to use.

Note: Since you are fetching the 'count(id)' you would have to group the List by the Account.id.
Although it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: select Enrolled_Flag__c,Electoral_Twin__c,Primary_SPID__c,GivenName__c,Family_Name__c,Date_of_Birth__c, count(id) from 
       Account GROUP BY Enrolled_Flag__c,Electoral_Twin__c,Primary_SPID__c,GivenName__c,Family_Name__c,Date_of_Birth__c HAVING 
       count(id)>1 this is my query

Comment: in my query i have field type checkbox and date of birth .what is the syntax for that one Enrolled_flag__c=(boolean)a.get('Enrolled_flag__c'),am i correct and for date of birth dateofbirth=(Number)a.get('dateofbirth')

Comment: You can find here all the primitive data types in apex  : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm . For your case I am guessing that the dateofbirth should be of type 'Date'